# SugarCRM access denied during set entry

Tags: soap, sugarcrm

I need help, I get access denied when I try to add an ID in the parameters. 
I know to create a custom id, I must add

```
array('name' => 'new_with_id', 'value' => '1'), <----

array('name' => 'id', 'value' => '1111-1111')
```

It won't work, it works when I delete that line but that meant it'll just create a generated id.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a need to create a new record and assign its id property "manually" (eg. *before* calling SugarBean::save()) I use something like this:

```
$meeting = new Meeting();
$meeting->new_with_id = true;
$meeting->id = create_quid();  // see include/utils.php
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is go to your SugarCRM administration, go to repair and repair roles, with this you update the permissions of modules that have assets in SugarCRM.